# How to update libsoup to the latest version

Tags: gnome, updates, package-management, 13.10

I would like to update my **libsoup** to the latest version as found in the [launchpad for libsoup2.4](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsoup2.4). The last time I tried to install it from source I ended up with a bricked Linux system.

Can I update it through the **package manager** somehow? I am on Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it for 13.10 here, needed to be able to add radio stations consistently
(it's also in 14.04 trusty repo which may be usable in 13.10

https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/rbaudiocd-fix